# Matzah baking in a frying pan - flipping the matzah

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, matzah

Do regular matzah bakeries flip the matzah in the middle of baking? I heard from a rabbi not to do that, but I see videos where they flip it. What are the issues here?
Update: I want to make the question a little more specific, restricting to a case where someone makes matzah in a covered frying pan. Unlike a regular matzah oven, flipping the matzah here involves uncovering the pan, and lifting the matzah itself off the source of heat. That would be more similar to completely removing the matzah from a regular matzah oven, and then putting it back - and that's already something the poskim do not allow lechatchilah, if you did it when it wasn't already baked enough.
Let me quote that source for some clarity [(Shulchan Aruch 461(3) in the Rema)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.461.3?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he):

> מצה שנאפת עד שאם פורסין אותה אין חוטין נמשכים ממנה יוצאים בה
> *הגה
> ויש
> ליזהר שלא ללקחה מן התנור קודם לכן (ד"ע) ולהחזירה כי תוכל לבא לידי
> חימוץ (מהרי"ל):*
> *You should be careful not to take [the matzah] from the
> oven before [it reaches the stage where threads of
> dough no longer connect when broken], and put it back, because it could come to
> become chametz.*

And in the [Biur Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.461.3?lang=bi&with=Biur%20Halacha&lang2=he) on that, ד"ה ויש ליזהר:

> בא"ד ובהג"ה שהזהיר ליקח וכו' ולהחזירה, דמשמע אפילו רוצה להחזירה
> מיד
> היינו רק לכתחלה ומשום שמא ישהה ויבוא לידי חימוץ

*"The reason not to do it, even right away, is because you might wait and it could come to chimutz."* I wonder if that applies in this case, where you didn't take it out to look it over, but rather to flip it as quickly as possible.

Comment: These folks don't flip theirs, but they're Jews from the Karaite tradition, so they can make their own at home. I haven't heard whether or not Orthodox bakeries flip theirs.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NR3mhY-sFRk

Comment: Judging from youtube, I see a number of bakeries where they don't flip the matzah _because they don't need to_, but occasionally do when it's needed, like they want to leave one matzah while they pick up the rest, so they flip that one while they're picking up the rest. In these matzah ovens we're talking about 15 second total anyhow.

Comment: I still have my question in a covered frying pan, I think.

Comment: As a practical matter, you would want to use an uncovered frying pan so the steam coming off the matzah rises instead of condensing on the lid and dripping back down as hot water

Comment: The few people I've had the privilege of making homemade matzah with do indeed flip it halfway through, they use a tiny inexpensive device like this: https://www.fruugo.co.il/1800w-pizza-maker-bread-making-machine-toaster-steak-machines-electric-household-pizza-baking-pan-fz5/p-249905628-540170161?language=en&ac=google&asc=pmax&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqdqvBhCPARIsANrmZhMtz2cQTXpnyyYAhESTRYcKlvlOVBjHnfA5FfeXwmqfGooryC1U8Y0aAmiyEALw_wcB and do not close the lid

Comment: @יהושעק See Igros Moshe OH 153: He says it needs to be covered so that the top of the matzah bakes. I think you could set the cover so that the steam can escape.